# DB:seed file for Laravel 4 working fine on local host, not working on Mediatemple gridserver?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, seeding

I have a Laravel 4 db:seed file that I am trying to use on mediatemple gridserver.  I was able to run a migration with artisan fine (php artisan migrate), and make the tables, but I am not able to seed the tables.  This database seeding worked fine on local host.  It is only now on a live server that I am experiencing any issues with it.  Here is the seed file:

```
ArtistsTableSeeder.php:

class ArtistsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        // Uncomment the below to wipe the table clean before populating
        // DB::table('artists')->delete();

        $artists = array(

        );

        $Artists = [
            ['stage_name' => 'Blah', 'city' => 'Blah', 'state' => 'blah', 'video_path' => 'youtube.com', 'image_path' => 'filepickerimage', 'soundcloud_profile' => 'https://soundcloud.com/', 'description' => '', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime]


        ];

        // Uncomment the below to run the seeder
        DB::table('artists')->insert($Artists);
    }

}
```

It is spitting out this error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"syntax error, unexpected '['","file":"\/nfs\/c09\/h04\/mnt\/139243\/domains\/crowdsets.com\/html\/app\/database\/seeds\/ArtistsTableSeeder.php","linemichaelsutyak.com@n26:/home/139243/domains/crowdsets.com/html$ php artisan db:seed
```

It is complaining about the line that starts the array:

```
$Artists = [
```

I have no idea why this is happening.  A little help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That syntax error you get is probably caused by a feature that has been added in PHP 5.4 ([short array syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays)), so I'd guess your hoster still runs 5.3.x.
You should check the PHP version on the mediatemple grid server and update it if necessary.

Comment: Worst comes to worst, you can simply change any instance of `[...]` to `array(...)` in your code. Laravel is all php 5.3 compliant - it doesn't use any 5.4 specific syntax.

Comment: On mediatemple, it gave me the option for my domains to use php 5.3.6 or 5.5.0.  When I use 5.5.0, I still get the same syntax error.

Comment: I cannot restart the server using gridserver on media temple..i'm still getting the error